# Why Thread.currentThread().interrupt() be called?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read a sample code given by Bloch in *Effective Java* as shown below:

[image]

Now, I want to make it clear that for which purpose `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()` was called. I read explanation given by that book but I'm still confused:

[image]

Can anyone explain it a step further?

Comment: What part you didn't understand?

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun:I want to know that why Thread.currentThread().interrupt() be called,cause current thread is already interrupted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you catch an `InterruptedException`, the thread's interrupted flag is cleared. By calling `Thread.currentThread().interrupt()`, you set the interrupted flag again so clients higher up the stack know the thread has been interrupted and can react accordingly. In the example, the `Executor` is one such client.

You may want to read [this article](https://itblackbelt.wordpress.com/2006/05/24/dealing-with-interruptedexception-by-brian-goetz/) for a more thorough explanation.

Comment: So why not just not catch the exception, if the goal is to allow the executor to handle it?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It's a checked exception so you would have to use a Callable instead of Runnable. But that would be simpler.

Comment: @PeterLawrey: Ah, of course. And `interrupt` doesn't throw that exception where you call it, it causes that exception to be thrown for anything waiting on the thread. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much,I read that article and I have learned a lot from it.

Comment: I still get something to ask for your help that I don't know why it will cause a thread starvation deadlock here if it doesn't call Thread.currentThread().interrupt.

Comment: The interruption remark from the text is not related to the thread starvation it mentions just before.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin seems IBM has moved or taken down the article. I've edited the link to point to a duplication. Anyway googling "Brian Goetz Dealing with InterruptedException" should yield some alternatives as well.

Answer (score 2):

When a method like `await()` is interrupted or called in an interrupted thread, **the interrupted flag is cleared** so subsequent calls don't immediately stop due to a previous interrupt.

To avoid this, the `catch` clause re-interrupts the thread so the flag is still set and the *code outside `run` knows about it being interrupted* and handles it appropriately (usually shutting down the worker).